# Why is node-gyp failing to rebuild?

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

Hello i have tried to run the following command `npm run start` but it didn't work.

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild 'C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard'.
For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".

Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
at NodeGyp.rebuildModule (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\src\module-type\node-gyp.js:120:19)      
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuildNodeGypModule (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\src\module-rebuilder.js:98:9)
    at async ModuleRebuilder.rebuild (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\src\module-rebuilder.js:128:14)
    at async Rebuilder.rebuildModuleAt (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:149:13)     
    at async Rebuilder.rebuild (C:\Users\cantr\Desktop\Stage ingénieur KOMILFO SPORT\Sail Vision\Dashboard\node_modules\@electron\rebuild\lib\src\rebuild.js:112:17)
```

Then i tried to update npm, to verify version (python, npm) and to run a rebuild.

I didn't know where my error came from ?

Regards,

Comment: Note how it says: `For more information, rerun with the DEBUG environment variable set to "electron-rebuild".` Try that

Comment: Sorry i have tried to run the command "DEBUG=electron-rebuild" but it didn't work because this command isn't recognized.

Comment: An environment variable is a variable you pass to a process before running it. You will be running the same command, but you need to set that environment variable to get further debug logs. This is trivially done on linux, you'll have to look up how to do it on your windows machine.

Answer (score -1):

Solved after I installed python3 and upgraded `node-sass`:

```bash
npm install node-sass@latest
```